# What is a word for a symbol of something that simultaneously is a manifestation of the thing it symbolizes?

Tags: nouns, symbols

I am looking for a word that would mean a symbol of some quality or entity that simultaneously IS the thing it symbolizes.

An example would be an Egyptian ankh which is the word 'life', the amulet of life, and in representations can be considered to, magically-religiously, be or contain the essence of life.

Similarly the representation of an eye in a face, or sarcophagus, is not only a representation, but provides sight to the deceased.

Comment: Since the ankh doesn't actually provide life nor the eye actually let the dead see, aren't those still strictly symbols? As opposed to, for example, in lexicography, autological words which are words to describe other things but also describe themselves, such as "polysyllabic" (a word with multiple syllables meaning "word with multiple syllables"), or that ultimate example, "word". These describe real-world things, while also being in the real-world things which match that description.

Comment: In the religious/magical system I am talking about there would be (at least on some levels) a real belief that these things DID provide those values, in the same way that they statues of the gods were inhabited by them.

Comment: Hmm, there are similar sentiments in the Catholic belief of transubstantiation of the eucharist... maybe a Catholic glossary will turn up something relevant. I'll have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also think that cultural anthropology, archaeology, or something the lines of Joseph Campbell may have something useful. I shall go dig out my old textbooks. Possibly Erik Hornung may have something.

Answer (score 1):

One sense of the word [*avatar*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avatar) might work.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2 b** : an embodiment (as of a concept or philosophy) often in a person
> // She was regarded as an *avatar* of charity and concern for the poor.

Although it says it is often the embodiment of something in a person, the same sense could also be applied to something inanimate.

In other words, the ankh was seen as an avatar (embodiment or vessel) of life.

Comment: Thanks! Avatar was one of the words I was considering.

Answer (score -1):

Epitome comes close.  The Oxford online English dictionary defines it as "A person or thing that is a perfect example of a particular quality or type."

Wiktionary defines it as

1) The embodiment or encapsulation of a class of items.

2) A representative example.

3) The height or the best.

4) A brief summary of a text.

Comment: embodiment might actually be closer, it made my short list of terms. :) Thanks!